# Ajax.ActionLink, how to send the selected object in the partial view? asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I guess this is a noob question, but here it comes:

I have a list of products:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.code) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.date)) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.category) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.description) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:F}", item.price)) %>
        </td>
     ......
}
```

And a partial view  after all of these (in the same page):

```
 <div id="productForEdit">
             <fieldset>
                 <legend>Your Selected Product</legend>
                 <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Products/Edit", productObject); %>
             </fieldset>
    </div>
```

How do I use Ajax.ActionLink, so that when I will click the description of a product, the product will be plugged in the Partial View from the bottom of the page?
I tried some combination with `UpdateTargetId="productForEdit"`, but I had no success.

The purpose is to have a quick edit tool in the page.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295835/how-can-i-load-partial-view-inside-the-view and here http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<td>
  <%= Ajax.ActionLink(Html.Encode(item.description), /* link text */
                      "GetProduct", /* action name */
                      "Product", /* controller name */
                      new { productCode = Model.code }, /* route values */
                      new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                          UpdateTargetId = "productForEdit" }) %>
</td>
```

This does expect a `ProductController` with an action named `GetProduct`, which takes a parameter `productCode`. Have this action return the view "Products/Edit".
You could also pass the whole product as a parameter to the action method, but that changes nothing to the basic idea. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer and this http://blog.goyello.com/2009/09/24/asp-net-mvc-issue-with-ajax-actionlink/ solved my problem.
Thank you!