# How can I load Partial view inside the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am very confuse with this partial view.

I want to load a partial view inside my main view.

Here is the simple example.

I am loading Index.cshtml of the Homecontroller Index action as a main page.

In index.cshtml, I am creating a link via

```
@Html.ActionLink("load partial view","Load","Home")
```

in HomeController I am adding a new Action called

```
public PartialViewResult Load()
{
    return PartialView("_LoadView");
}
```

in _LoadView.cshmtl I am just having a

```
<div>
    Welcome !!
</div>
```

BUT, when run the project, index.cshtml renders first and shows me the link "Load Partial View". when I click on that it goes to new page instade of rendering the welcome message from _LoadView.cshtml into the index.cshtml.

What can be wrong?

Note: I don't want to load page through AJAX or don't want to use Ajax.ActionLink .

Answer (score 155, accepted):

If you want to load the partial view directly inside the main view you could use the `Html.Action` helper:

```
@Html.Action("Load", "Home")
```

or if you don't want to go through the Load action use the HtmlPartialAsync helper:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_LoadView")
```

If you want to use `Ajax.ActionLink`, replace your `Html.ActionLink` with:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "load partial view", 
    "Load", 
    "Home", 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }
)
```

and of course you need to include a holder in your page where the partial will be displayed:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Also don't forget to include:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in your main view in order to enable `Ajax.*` helpers. And make sure that unobtrusive javascript is enabled in your web.config (it should be by default):

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: works fine...so that means if i want to use it with @Html.ActionLink its goona act as a normal request and open up the parial view in new page? ...

Comment: @patel.milanb, exactly. Html.ActionLink renders a normal anchor in html which simply performs a GET request to the given url and it redirects the browser to it. Because you have pointed it to the Load action which only returns a partial, the browser gets redirected and displays this partial.

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much, for asking and answering this! I have been trying to get this to work for hours, never quite getting the syntax right. For the last hour or two (plus breaks), I was trying to get this version above from Darin to work, but I left out the "don't forget to include" line and couldn't believe that would make the difference between loading the whole page and loading into the div (I expected an error, not a display change), but it did.

Comment: Hi, In my scenario, I want to switch between short view and extended view. I placed an `Ajax.ActionLink` in the short view and I set the `UpdateTargetId` to a parent div's id. Now when I click the link the ajax result replaces the entire page.

Comment: helping you get to 500K

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you @DarinDimitrov for such a perfect one. I was sure it was you before even I saw your name. :)

Comment: plus as suggested by @Scott below, need to import these two @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"),
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") to get  Ajax.Action link rendering partial page on same page.

Comment: The @Html.Partial-Method did it for me.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You said If you want to load the partial view directly inside the main view you could use the Html.Action helper:

`@Html.Action("Load", "Home")` This means I should create a method in my controller which is called "Load" and in that method I should write  `return PartialView(...)` ?

Answer (score 15):

I had exactly the same problem as Leniel. I tried fixes suggested here and a dozen other places. The thing that finally worked for me was simply adding

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

to my layout...

Comment: I also spend hours to beat this problem. In my default mvc4 template for "basic mvc application" I have @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"), but not @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval"). So I just add the second and partial views start to render on the same page instead of new one. Thank you.

Comment: even for me it didn't work until I imported these two imports.

Answer (score 5):

If you do it with a `@Html.ActionLink()` then loading the PartialView is handled as a normal request when clicking a anchor-element, i.e. load new page with the reponse of the PartialViewResult method. 
If you want to load it immedialty, then you use `@Html.RenderPartial("_LoadView")` or `@Html.RenderAction("Load")`.
 If you want to do it upon userinteraction (i.e. clicking a link) then you need to use AJAX --> `@Ajax.ActionLink()`

Comment: the above solution works fine...so that means if i want to use it with @Html.ActionLink its goona act as a normal request and open up the parial view in new page? just want to clear my mind with the partial view...

Answer (score 5):

For me this worked after I downloaded  AJAX Unobtrusive library via NuGet :

```
 Search and install via NuGet Packages:   Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

Than add in the view the references to jquery and AJAX Unobtrusive:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"> </script>
```

Next the Ajax *ActionLink* and the *div* were we want to render the results:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Click Here to Load the Partial View", 
    "ActionName", 
    null, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "toUpdate" }
)

<div id="toUpdate"></div>
```

Comment: I  had followed a tutorial on youtube to implement this and I hadn't installed the `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`. This is despite the fact that I had installed jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.min.js. Thanks you saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to populate contents of your partial view inside your view you can use

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName")
```

or

```
{@Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName");}
```

if you want to make server request and process the data and then return partial view to you main view filled with that data you can use

```
...
    @Html.Action("Load", "Home")
...

public PartialViewResult Load()
{
    return PartialView("_LoadView");
}
```

if you want user to click on the link and then populate the data of partial view you can use:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Click Here to Load the Partial View", 
    "ActionName", 
    "ControlerName",
    null, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "toUpdate" }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Small tweek to the above

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Click Here to Load the Partial View", 
    "ActionName", 
    "ControlerName",
    null, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "toUpdate" }
)

<div id="toUpdate"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

RenderParital is Better to use for performance.

```
{@Html.RenderPartial("_LoadView");}
```