# Change partial view on link press

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have something like

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial(@"~/Views/Management/_Main.cshtml"); }
```

Can I change this view without page refreshing? I mean, I want to render few partials on one place. Like gallery, may be. I mean, I press the link - some section loaded, depending on argument.
First I think about - master page (Layout page). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically load a partial view into a div without a page reload by using the `@Ajax.ActionLink()` method.

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295835/how-can-i-load-partial-view-inside-the-view).

Comment: Hi, In my scenario, I want to switch between short view and extended view. I placed an `Ajax.ActionLink` in the short view and I set the `UpdateTargetId` to a parent div's id. Now when I click the link the ajax result replaces the entire page.