# Loading a partial view inside a main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am trying to load a partial view inside of the main view, and a similar question was posted here - ' [How can i load Partial view inside the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295835/how-can-i-load-partial-view-inside-the-view) ' explaining how to use ajax actionlinks, but I still can't seem to get this working without the partial view displaying on a brand new page.

Here is the basis of my code that is in the main view,

```
        <td>

            @Ajax.ActionLink(
                item.FirstName,
                "DisplayApplication",
                new { ID = item.PersonID },
                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ApplicationByPerson" }
            )
        </td>
...

<div id="ApplicationByPerson"></div>
```

Then later down the page I have a Div called "ApplicationByPerson" I want my partial view displayed in.

In my controller I then have the code,

```
    public ActionResult DisplayApplication(int ID)
    {
        var tmp = db.Persons.Where(x => x.PersonID == ID).Include(y => y.Apps).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(tmp.Apps);
    }
```

The right information is being returned to the view, but it is displaying by itself as a new view. I'm sure it is something simple I am doing wrong.

Comment: Probably because you are missing the required jquery files `jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-js`

Comment: ' itself as a new view ' means??

Comment: At the bottom of my page I have      
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js") just before my bodytag finished in the _layout file, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Are you referring  layout in partial view?

Comment: Check in the browser that the file is actually being loaded, at that javascript has not been disabled.

Comment: No, it is in the layout for the main file with the header and footer that are used for every page, is that correct? JavaScript is enabled and the file is being fully loaded.

Comment: Possibly you have the scripts out of order, or are including them multiple times

Comment: I only mention it the once right before the close of my body tag. And the only things also there are the scripts.render() for jquery and bootstrap (I have tried p;lacing these before and after - no difference). I think I did check correctly, but how would you check in the browser to make sure the file is being loaded correctly?

Comment: OK I finally got it working. You were right about the ordering. The ajax script needed to be loaded after JQuery.