# MVC modal popup from partial view - not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm developing an MVC webpage, where I'm intending to do Create and Edit operations via a pop-up. So, the idea is I click on the 'Create' button, a modal-popup appears with all the model fields empty and allows user to input. In the same way, when user double clicks on any row, the row would open up for edit via the same pop-up, this time with the details filled from that row.

So, for reusage, I have decided to develop a single partial view(that would be the pop-up) and accept 'Model' as input.

My problem is, no matter what I do, I'm not able to make the partial view come up as pop-up. (Note: my main parent Index view would accpet input as List

Here is my code:

MY Index view:

```
 @model List<TrackBuildConfig.DAL.Models.BuildModel>
 @{
    Layout = null;
  }

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Track Coverity and Nightly builds</h1>
        <h4>on your own!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row btn-group">

            @Html.ActionLink("Create a new record", "SaveData", "Home", new { configID = 0 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary modal-link", id = "btnCreate"})
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" id="modal-container" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content" style="width: 500px !important; margin:10px !important">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Script:

```
 $(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#btnCreate').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        $('#btnCreate').attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
        $('#modal-container').modal('show');
        return true;
    });
    }
});
```

Partial view _PartialModal.csHtml

```
@model TrackBuildConfig.DAL.Models.BuildModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
            <h4>Configure Coverity and Nightly builds</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="height: 400px;">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group row">

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            @Html.Label("Stream name", new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            @Html.DropDownList("BuildLocations", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BuildLocations, new { @class = "col-sm-6 form-control", id = "ddlBuildLocation" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            @Html.Label("Build Location", new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            @Html.DropDownList("Streams", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Streams, new { @class = "col-sm-6 form-control", id = "ddlStreams" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsCoverity)
                                    Enable Coverity
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsNightly)
                                    Enable Nightly build
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label style="color: red; font-weight: 300;" id="warningEnableBuild"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        @Html.Label("Email for Coverity", new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-8" style="width: 100%">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmailCoverity, new { @class = "form-control clsEmailCoverity", @placeholder = "Enter some value", @onkeyup = "return true;", @rows = "5", id = "txtEmailCoverity" })
                            @*<textarea id="txtEmailCoverity" class="form-control clsEmailCoverity" runat="server" rows="5" placeholder="Enter email IDs for Coverity builds" onkeyup="SetEmailForNightly()"></textarea>*@
                            <span class="help-block">Please add only comma separated addresses!</span>
                            <label style="color: red; font-weight: 300;" id="warningLabelCoverity"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        @Html.Label("Email for Nightly", new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-8" style="width: 100%">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmailNightly, new { @class = "form-control clsEmailNightly", @placeholder = "Enter some value", @onkeyup = "return true;", @rows = "5", id = "txtEmailNightly" })
                            @*<textarea id="txtEmailCoverity" class="form-control clsEmailCoverity" runat="server" rows="5" placeholder="Enter email IDs for Coverity builds" onkeyup="SetEmailForNightly()"></textarea>*@
                            <span class="help-block">Please add only comma separated addresses!</span>
                            <label style="color: red; font-weight: 300;" id="warningLabelNightly"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" role="button">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller methods:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GetData getdata = new GetData();
        return View(getdata.GetDataFromTable());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveData()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    //[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SaveData(int configID)
    {
        BuildModel model = new BuildModel();

        PopulateBuildLocations();
        PopulateStreams();

        //Create
        if (configID != 0)
        {
            GetData getdata = new GetData();
            model = getdata.GetDataFromTable().Where(co => co.ConfigID == configID).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            model.BuildLocation = "";
            model.EmailCoverity = "";
            model.EmailNightly = "";
            model.IsCoverity = false;
            model.IsNightly = false;
        }

        return PartialView("_PartialModal", model);
    }

    public void PopulateBuildLocations()
    {
        string reportTypes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ddlStreams"].ToString();
        ViewBag.BuildLocations = reportTypes.Split('|')
            .Select((text, value) => new SelectListItem { Text = text, Value = value.ToString() });
    }

    public void PopulateStreams()
    {
        List<string> lstStreams = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            lstStreams.Add("Stream " + i);
        }
        ViewBag.Streams = lstStreams.Select((text, value) => new SelectListItem { Text = text, Value = value.ToString() });
    }
}
```

This is the link I used as reference. [Reference](https://codemagik.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/render-mvc-partial-view-inside-bootstrap-modal-dialog/#comment-162)

Comment: You have mentioned `In the same way, when user double clicks on any row,` Can you tell me where you are binding the list ?

Comment: There are so many errors in your code. You should not write `HTML Tag, HEAD, BODY` inside your partial view. You are not binding the list of data anywhere. **SaveData** Post method doing nothing. Not calling your partial view anywhere. I would suggest to check this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295909/2376652) to understand how to load a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Please put my code in your visual studio and see that it works.

Controller/View Model/Classes:

```
public class BuildModel
{
    public string theBuildModel { get; set; }
    public int ConfigID { get; set; }
    public string BuildLocation { get; set; }
    public string EmailCoverity { get; set; }
    public string EmailNightly { get; set; }
    public bool IsCoverity { get; set; }
    public bool IsNightly { get; set; }
}

public class GetData
{
    public IList<BuildModel> GetDataFromTable()
    {
        IList<BuildModel> list = new List<BuildModel>();
        var buildModel1 = new BuildModel { theBuildModel = "one" };
        var buildModel2 = new BuildModel { theBuildModel = "two" };
        var buildModel3 = new BuildModel { theBuildModel = "three" };
        list.Add(buildModel1);
        list.Add(buildModel2);
        list.Add(buildModel3);
        return list;
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult SaveData(BuildModel buildModel)
    {
        GetData getdata = new GetData();
        var model = getdata.GetDataFromTable();
        return View("IndexStackOverflow", model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult SaveData(int configID)
    {
        BuildModel model = new BuildModel();

        PopulateBuildLocations();
        PopulateStreams();

        //Create
        if (configID != 0)
        {
            GetData getdata = new GetData();
            model = getdata.GetDataFromTable().Where(co => co.ConfigID == configID).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            model.BuildLocation = "";
            model.EmailCoverity = "";
            model.EmailNightly = "";
            model.IsCoverity = false;
            model.IsNightly = false;
        }

        return PartialView("_PartialModal", model);
    }

    public void PopulateBuildLocations()
    {
        string reportTypes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ddlStreams"].ToString();
        ViewBag.BuildLocations = reportTypes.Split('|')
            .Select((text, value) => new SelectListItem { Text = text, Value = value.ToString() });
    }

    public void PopulateStreams()
    {
        List<string> lstStreams = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            lstStreams.Add("Stream " + i);
        }
        ViewBag.Streams = lstStreams.Select((text, value) => new SelectListItem { Text = text, Value = value.ToString() });
    }

    public ActionResult IndexStackOverflow()
    {
        GetData getdata = new GetData();
        return View(getdata.GetDataFromTable());
    }
```

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="ddlStreams" value="text1|value1"/>
</appSettings>
```

View:

```
@model List<Testy20161006.Controllers.BuildModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexStackOverflow</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @*YOU MUST PUT THE NEXT LINE FOLLOWING IN YOUR CODE-NUGET IF YOU NEED TO GET THE SCRIPT*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>This is part of the Main Page</h1>
        <h1>Partial View rendered in result</h1>
        <h1>Track Coverity and Nightly builds</h1>
        <h4>on your own!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row btn-group">

            @*@Html.ActionLink("Create a new record", "SaveData", "Home", new { configID = 0 },
                new { @class = "btn btn-primary modal-link", id = "btnCreate" })*@
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveData", "Home", new { configID = 0 },
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "result",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    OnFailure = "error",
                    HttpMethod = "Get"
                }))
            {
                <input id="btnCreate" type="submit" value="Create a new record" class="btn btn-primary modal-link" />

            }
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Partial View in shared folder:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.BuildModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    })
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Configure Coverity and Nightly builds</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-body" style="height: 400px;">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group row">

                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    @Html.Label("Stream name", new { @class = "control-label" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("BuildLocations", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BuildLocations, new { @class = "col-sm-6 form-control", id = "ddlBuildLocation" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">

                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    @Html.Label("Build Location", new { @class = "control-label" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Streams", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Streams, new { @class = "col-sm-6 form-control", id = "ddlStreams" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsCoverity)
                                            Enable Coverity
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsNightly)
                                            Enable Nightly build
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <label style="color: red; font-weight: 300;" id="warningEnableBuild"></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                @Html.Label("Email for Coverity", new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
                                <div class="col-sm-8" style="width: 100%">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmailCoverity, new { @class = "form-control clsEmailCoverity", @placeholder = "Enter some value", @onkeyup = "return true;", @rows = "5", id = "txtEmailCoverity" })
                                    @*<textarea id="txtEmailCoverity" class="form-control clsEmailCoverity" runat="server" rows="5" placeholder="Enter email IDs for Coverity builds" onkeyup="SetEmailForNightly()"></textarea>*@
                                    <span class="help-block">Please add only comma separated addresses!</span>
                                    <label style="color: red; font-weight: 300;" id="warningLabelCoverity"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                @Html.Label("Email for Nightly", new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
                                <div class="col-sm-8" style="width: 100%">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmailNightly, new { @class = "form-control clsEmailNightly", @placeholder = "Enter some value", @onkeyup = "return true;", @rows = "5", id = "txtEmailNightly" })
                                    @*<textarea id="txtEmailCoverity" class="form-control clsEmailCoverity" runat="server" rows="5" placeholder="Enter email IDs for Coverity builds" onkeyup="SetEmailForNightly()"></textarea>*@
                                    <span class="help-block">Please add only comma separated addresses!</span>
                                    <label style="color: red; font-weight: 300;" id="warningLabelNightly"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" role="button">Save changes</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```